# Remove the "thanks for flagging" popup after the user has raised a number of flags

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, comment-flags, popups

Currently, whenever anyone flags a comment, they get this popup:

[image: thanks for flagging]

or, more recently:

[image: Thanks for flagging! We take your reports seriously.]

I personally find this really annoying, especially since I flag a great many comments a day (on the order of hundreds over a few different sites).

On the site that the above screenshot was taken on, I've raised 2,600+ comment flags. I don't *need* this "thanks" any more - I know how this system works, I don't need the "encouragement". It helps reinforce things the first few times you flag,  but to anyone experienced with the system it's just annoying (especially given how *long* it stays).

Can this simply be disabled for users who have raised more than, say, 25 helpful comment flags?

Comment: This appears to me just a confirmation popup letting you know that a flag has successfully been raised.

Comment: @AJ - that's already covered by the flag icon turning red.

Comment: SE is going towards being more welcoming. Such a banner is a step in that direction, I don't see any harm in it. If for some odd reason you really find it annoying, install a userscript that will hide it. (and possibly all pop up banners in SE.)

Comment: Possible complication: there's a variant response for rude/abusive comments, something like "we're sorry you had to see that", and we probably still want to show that at least once or twice.  So consider the case where you have 50 helpful *other* comment flags but this is your first rude one.

Comment: Yes, I definitely liked seeing the "sorry you had to see that" variant while this just plain thanks one neither bothers nor helps me. It can stay or go but keep the longer one for sure.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: A site can be welcoming for *new* users and still not annoy *existing* users by way of intelligent defaults. I'd suggest disabling the Thanks for users who have raised more than 5 helpful flags or who already have more than 500 reputation. This particular pop-up covers comments I want to flag, thus interfering with how quickly I can flag. And I've raised well over 3,500 flags.

Comment: It wouldn’t be so bad if It went away quickly enough that I didn’t need to click the little “x”, so maybe just make it time out faster as you have more helpful flags.

Comment: @ColleenV How quickly? I think it's currently set for only about three seconds. It does need to be readable to people who don't know what it says already. :) I'm also guessing but I think it'd be easier to just have it not appear at all than to have it disappear more quickly based on flags.

Comment: @Catija Apparently the time it takes for me to make sure it doesn’t say anything new, and then move my mouse to close it is far less than 3 seconds. I have never let it time out. I do like the confirmation that the message was received though and might be a little concerned that something was broken if it it stopped showing.