# New "Thank you" when flagging a comment

Tags: feature-request, support, comment-flags

The interface for flagging comments has changed. When I flag a comment as "Not relevant" (or anything else, but that's the one I use when working the queues) I get a green "Thank you" message. EVERY single time.

I don't need that. I don't want that. It's noise. It blocks whatever is below it meaning I either need to scroll or manually dismiss the thing. When I'm working the queues and come across a post in the Re-open list (especially) there's often a lot of back-and-forth that's been taken care of. I don't need this extra, time-consuming obstruction.

If it can't be turned off, could it at least be set to disappear after five seconds? Then I'd know I'm able to flag the next comment that's cluttering a Q&A.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313452/remove-the-thanks-for-flagging-popup-after-the-user-has-raised-a-number-of-fla

Comment: It does disappear after a few seconds. Is it not disappearing at all for you? In that case, that's a bug.

Comment: @Sonictheinclusivehedgehog No, it's not going away without my doing anything. If I scroll it off the screen it disappears. Or do some other kind of "work". But when I'm in flagging mode for site moderation I need to be able to scan all the comments, and the next one I need is usually partially hidden...