# Automatically dismiss 'Please consider adding a comment' message when loading next review

Tags: bug, review, down-votes, notification-bar

Whenever you cast a downvote, if you have less than 2k reputation, you get a message reminding you

> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

This used to be shown near the downvote button, but a few days ago it changed into a banner at the top of the screen.

Now when reviewing First Posts, after clicking 'I'm done', a new review item is dynamically loaded into the page. However, this banner is not dismissed (see below). I consider this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) since I'm sure the old message *was* automatically dismissed, and old-style 'Thanks, we'll take a look at it' popups after flagging a post are still dismissed automatically.

[image]

Comment: Another "toast" message... These aren't attached to any element, so the message doesn't get automatically destroyed when moving to the next review. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313486/new-thank-you-when-flagging-a-comment