# Re-voting for reopening doesn't show notification message after second vote, but re-voting for deletion does

Tags: support, bug, flags, notifications

If you re-voting for post deletion notification message will be shown each time.

> [image]

But for re-opening it works differently. Notification message shown only for first click.

> [image]

Looks inconsistent.

Comment: Probably because the reopen notification hasn't been ported yet to the new [toast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320760/automatically-dismiss-please-consider-adding-a-comment-message-when-loading-ne#comment1051223_320760) style for notifications...

Comment: Might it be possible for you to capture a version of this in English? I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at here, sorry. (Also, is this still applicable? I think things have changed a bit with reopening since this was posted.)