# "This post has been edited" banner remains visible after completing the review queue item

Tags: bug, review, edits

I encountered the following situation in the First Posts review queue: when editing the post, it was edited by the author too, so I got the familiar banner

> This post has been edited 1 time since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.

After saving the edit and clicking 'I'm Done', the next item loads (except that I reached the end of the queue) but the banner remained visible:

[image]

Comment: That's odd. I assume the banner should be automatically dismissed when the view is no longer at the item that triggered it.

Comment: Yeah, I now remember there's *another* notification with the same problem: [Automatically dismiss 'Please consider adding a comment' message when loading next review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320760/295232)