# Toast notifications are not being shown; a TypeError in `StackExchange.helpers.showToast` is thrown instead

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript

Some [toast notifications](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toast#Noun) (i.e. those banners as shown [in this screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320760/289905)) are not being shown; an error is visible in the console instead.

This bug applies to Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange (possibly others) but not to Stack Overflow (possibly others). The JS sources for these are always a bit different, with the Metas having a more up-to-date version, if I recall correctly.

### Case 1

Flag or vote to close a post.

Expected result: the flag dialog closes, you get the familiar *“Thanks, we’ll take a look at it”* toast notification.

But instead, the flag or close vote dialog doesn’t close, the toast notification does not appear, an error is thrown. The flag or close vote still goes through.

### Case 2

Retract the flag or close vote again.

Expected result: the flag dialog closes, you get the familiar *“Your vote is retracted”* toast notification.

But instead, all the symptoms of Case 1 emerge, and a loading GIF is displayed next to the <kbd>Retract flag</kbd> button. The retraction still goes through.

---

The error is this: *“Uncaught `TypeError`: can’t access property "`htmlEncode`", `this` is `undefined`”* at stub.en.js:1:37708.

The error occurs inside `StackExchange.helpers.showToast`, at part of an expression that looks like `o.useRawHtml || (e = this.htmlEncode(e))`, after it’s called from an obfuscated function in `full.en.js`: `(...t) => e()(...t)`. `e() === StackExchange.helpers.showToast` holds true.

It’s a bit difficult to backtrack through the obfuscated code, but it is clear, here, that `this.htmlEncode` was supposed to refer to `StackExchange.helpers.htmlEncode`, but the `showToast` isn’t bound and there’s no way for `e()(...t)` to be called with any non-undefined `this` context.

Other instances where `this` is used inside the `StackExchange.helpers` object appear to work correctly, and usually `StackExchange.helpers` is used directly instead of `this`; that would fix the bug here as well: `o.useRawHtml || (e = StackExchange.helpers.htmlEncode(e))` instead of `o.useRawHtml || (e = this.htmlEncode(e))`.

---

This is almost certainly related to [the JavaScript migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/289905).

I will do some more debugging — almost certainly the problem is more extensive, but this bug report should be enough for Stack Exchange to fix this.

The modals not being dismissed automatically appears to be specific to questions. Inline error pop-ups seem to work correctly. Toast notifications shown when casting or retracting *comment* flags seem to work correctly. I don’t know if the *“Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.”* toast works correctly.

The methods `showErrorMessage`, `showErrorPopup`, `showInfoMessage`, `showSuccessMessage`, and `showBannerMessage` all use `this.showMessage` or `this.showErrorMessage`. It’s worth checking if these refer to the correct `this` as well.

Comment: _Hooray_, this seems to have been fixed, but _boo_, this seems to have been replaced by [a different bug](/q/377743/289905) (maybe)! At any rate, I can confirm that the JS has now changed and the bug is no longer reproducible. @JourneymanGeek Feel free to retag this as [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: I think I'll wait till someone who knows what actually was done to retag it :D

Comment: FYI, there is a way to get the unobfuscated source code: https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js. The source for the helper should be in the [stub.en.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js), though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These specific messages have been fixed.

> close vote or flag vote
> initial or retraction
> show toast properly

Comment: This bug is still relevant: [Badly escaped HTML results in plain text instead of markup in toast notifications (e.g. "You can&#39;t vote for your own post".)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377743/badly-escaped-html-results-in-plain-text-instead-of-markup-in-toast-notification)

Comment: @nicael noted - the fix for that is awaiting PR approval, should be done soon